# Why React App Not Rendering Matrix on Screen?

Tags: reactjs, matrix, colormatrix

1.Create a 3x3 matrix
2.When you click on a box - color should change to green
3.When you click on the last box, all colors should change to orange in sequence of their clicks (original clicks)

I'm working on a React application where I have a component called Matrix that is supposed to display a 3x3 matrix. However, I'm facing an issue where the matrix is not rendering on the screen when I run the application.

Here's the relevant code:

Matrix.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; // Import React

const Matrix = () => {
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([
    ["white", "white", "white"],
    ["white", "white", "white"],
    ["white", "white", "white"]
  ]);

  const handleClick = (row, column) => {
    const newBoxes = [...boxes];
    newBoxes[row][column] = "green";
    setBoxes(newBoxes);
  };

  const handleLastBoxClick = () => {
    const newBoxes = [...boxes];
    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++) {
        newBoxes[i][j] = "orange";
      }
    }
    setBoxes(newBoxes);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Matrix</h1>
      <div className="matrix">
        {boxes.map((row, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="row">
            {row.map((cell, j) => (
              <div
                key={j}
                className="cell"
                style={{ background: cell }}
                onClick={() => handleClick(i, j)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => handleLastBoxClick()}
        disabled={boxes[2][2] !== "green"}
      >
        Change all colors to orange
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Matrix;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Matrix from "./Matrix";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Matrix />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Checked for Errors: I opened the browser's developer console and looked for error messages in the console. No errors were reported.

Comment: Is the button rendered? Or the `<h1>Matrix</h1>`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Both the <h1>Matrix</h1> and the button are indeed rendered and visible in the app. However, the issue I'm facing is with the rendering of the matrix itself, which is not displaying as expected.

Comment: So the error must be here `{/* ... (code for rendering the matrix) */}` or `matrix` css class has `display: none`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate your help. I've already checked the code for rendering the matrix, and it seems correct. Additionally, I've verified that the CSS class for the matrix (className="matrix") does not have display: none. Despite these checks, the matrix is still not rendering as expected. Any further insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use `<table><tr><td>` instead of `<div><div><div>` to render the matrix? Then you don't have to worry about the classNames. Otherwise this is more CSS question, what are the `matrix`, `row`, `cell` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxes are displaying in HTML, but divs are empty. You can see this by changing the style property to this:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: "red", width: "30px", height: "30px", borderStyle: "double" }}
```

Comment: Your suggestion to change the style properties in the code worked perfectly. Now, the boxes are not only displaying in the HTML but also have the intended red background color, border, and dimensions. Your help was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a content to the deepest `<div>` so that it has something to render. Something like:

```
<div
  key={j}
  className="cell"
  style={{ background: cell }}
  onClick={() => handleClick(i, j)}
> {` `} {i} {j}</div> {/* this is the changed line */}
```

Otherwise it will render a matrix of empty `div`s, 0x0 pixels.

But better to use `<table>` to render such content:

```
<table className="matrix">
        {boxes.map((row, i) => (
          <tr key={i} className="row">
            {row.map((cell, j) => (
              <td
                key={j}
                className="cell"
                style={{ background: cell }}
                onClick={() => handleClick(i, j)}
              />
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
```